# Linked Lists in C- adding a struct in sorted position

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "Book.h"


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Book * dummy = newBook("dummy", "dummy", 00000);

    printf("%s %s %ld", dummy->title, dummy->author, dummy->ISBN);

    dummy->next = NULL;


    Book* newishBook = newBook("Foo", "Chris", 1234);
    insertToList(newishBook, dummy);

    Book* another = newBook("Bar", "Jim", 23344);
    insertToList(another, dummy);

    Book* yet = newBook("Derp", "Bob", 999);
    insertToList(yet, dummy);

    displayList(dummy);

    searchISBN(999);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

Book* newBook(char* newTitle, char* newAuthor, long newISBN) {
    Book* new_book = malloc(sizeof(Book));

    strcpy(new_book->title, newTitle);
    strcpy(new_book->author, newAuthor);
    new_book->ISBN = newISBN;
    return new_book;
}



void insertToList(Book* bookToInsert, Book* dummy){
    Book* currentNode = dummy;
    Book* temp = malloc(sizeof(Book));

    if (currentNode->next == NULL){
        currentNode->next = bookToInsert;
        printf("Head");
    } else {
        currentNode= currentNode->next;        
        while(currentNode->ISBN > bookToInsert->ISBN){

            if (bookToInsert ->ISBN < currentNode->ISBN){
                // if isbn of current book more than current node, move to next current node
                //otherwise add here
                printf("Added");
                temp->next = currentNode->next;
                bookToInsert->next = currentNode->next;
                currentNode->next = temp->next;
            }
        }
    }
}

void displayList(Book* dummy){
    //start at dummy node-
    Book* currentNode = dummy;
    bool run = true;

    //print until next = null
    while(run==true){
        if (currentNode->next != NULL){
            printf("%s %s %ld \n", currentNode->title, currentNode->author, currentNode->ISBN); 
            currentNode = currentNode ->next;
        } else {
            run = false;
        }
    }    
}
```

This program is intended to create book structs which are the nodes of a linked list. A book is defined as follows in the header file Book.h:

```
#ifndef BOOK_H
#define BOOK_H

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


typedef struct book_t {
    char title[50];
    char author[30];
    long ISBN;
    struct Book *next;
} Book;

Book* newBook(char* newTitle, char* newAuthor, long newISBN);

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  /* BOOK_H */
```

I feel like my insertToList function is close to working, but I've got code-blindness from looking at it too wrong and I'm sure there's something really basic wrong with it. Currently there is no output- just an empty terminal, I believe the loop is not exiting properly. Uncommenting the printf statments "added" and "head" causes the program to loop indefinitely, outputting "added" to the terminal.

Comment: `newBook()` should ensure all fields are initialized.  You should not need to do `dummy->next = NULL;` in `main()` — that should be done by `newBook()`.

Comment: Also, your code does not compile cleanly — why are you posting code that does not compile?  You (claim to) have: `typedef struct book_t { …; struct Book *next; } Book;`.  You don't show the `struct Book` to which the `next` pointer points — it is not the `struct book_t`.  So you should be getting warnings about pointer type mismatches.

Comment: Also, your loop `while(currentNode->ISBN > bookToInsert->ISBN)` will never exit because the variables used in the condition never change inside the loop. Definitely, you need to think again your `insertToList` function.

Comment: The allocation of `temp` in `insertToList()` is puzzling; it looks likely to leak memory.  You're about to insert `bookToInsert`, so it isn't clear why you need `temp` except to confuse everyone.

Comment: Book would be contained in a header file (Book.h). I had removed irrelevant functions from the code but I will edit it to contain my exact program, which compiles.

Comment: temp is required to store the node's next value. That node's next value is then amended to point to the new item. The new item has its next value set to the value in temp.

Comment: You may well need the variable `temp` to hold a pointer; you most probably do not need to allocate memory for `temp` to point to with `malloc().  I haven't fully checked, but I'd be surprised indeed if that memory is not leaked — if the code survives long enough to leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure should be:

```
typedef struct Book {
    char title[50];
    char author[30];
    long ISBN;
    struct Book *next;
} Book;
```

The code could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Book.h"

Book *newBook(char *newTitle, char *newAuthor, long newISBN);
void displayList(Book *dummy);
void insertToList(Book *bookToInsert, Book *dummy);
void freeList(Book *head);

int main(void)
{
    Book *dummy = newBook("dummy", "dummy", 00000);

    printf("%s %s %ld\n", dummy->title, dummy->author, dummy->ISBN);

    printf("Newish\n");
    Book *newishBook = newBook("Foo", "Chris", 1234);
    insertToList(newishBook, dummy);
    displayList(dummy);

    printf("Another\n");
    Book *another = newBook("Bar", "Jim", 23344);
    insertToList(another, dummy);
    displayList(dummy);

    printf("Yet\n");
    Book *yet = newBook("Derp", "Bob", 999);
    insertToList(yet, dummy);
    displayList(dummy);

    //searchISBN(999);
    freeList(dummy);

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

Book *newBook(char *newTitle, char *newAuthor, long newISBN)
{
    Book *new_book = malloc(sizeof(Book));

    strcpy(new_book->title, newTitle);
    strcpy(new_book->author, newAuthor);
    new_book->ISBN = newISBN;
    new_book->next = NULL;
    return new_book;
}

void insertToList(Book *bookToInsert, Book *dummy)
{
    Book *currentNode = dummy;

    while (currentNode->next != NULL && currentNode->next->ISBN < bookToInsert->ISBN)
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    bookToInsert->next = currentNode->next;
    currentNode->next = bookToInsert;
}

void displayList(Book *dummy)
{
    Book *currentNode = dummy;

    while (currentNode != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s %s %ld\n", currentNode->title, currentNode->author, currentNode->ISBN);
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }
}

void freeList(Book *head)
{
    Book *bp = head;
    while (bp != 0)
    {
        Book *bn = bp->next;
        free(bp);
        bp = bn;
    }
}
```

This runs leak-free under [`valgrind`](http://www.valgrind.org/) thanks to the `freeList()` function being added and used.

Note how the list is printed after each entry is added.  This helps ensure that the list is built correctly.  Also note how each line of output ends with a newline.  You won't necessarily see printed data until you print the newline.  For debugging in particular, make sure you include newlines — but it is generally a good idea even when not debugging.

Answer (score 1):

insertToList function is not handling all the cases.

you begin by checking if the list is empty (correct)
the while loop onwards has missing logic. you should:

```
1) check if currentNode is larger (same as your if statement)
  a) if it is smaller, insert the book,
  b) if it is larger, you need another check:
      i) if currentNode has next !== NULL, move down and repeat loop
      ii) if next == NULL, add book at the end and return;
```